# Скрыть / Показать определенный div

Tags: javascript

Есть такая разметка и код который скрывает и показывает div, но проблема в том, что бы он заработал, мне надо div `conditions_input` поместить в div `conditions_check`, но я не могу этого сделать, так как у меня ломается другой код, как можно выйти из положения? Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
    <div class="conditions_check">                                        

   <span>The user must be subscribed to the chanal</span>
   <div class="conditions_arrow"></div>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="conditions_check">                                          

       <span>The user must have at least X subscribers</span>
       <div class="conditions_arrow"></div>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
        <input type="text">
</div>

    .conditions_check {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2.5vw;
    width: 99%;
    border-radius: 0.5vw;
    color: #170738;
    padding-left: 1vw;
    margin-top: 1vw;
 }

.conditions_check span {
    position: relative;
    top: -0.4vw;
    left: -0.375vw;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

.conditions_input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 99%;
}

.conditions_arrow {

    display: inline-block;
    width: .6vw;
    height: .6vw;
    background: red;
    background-size: 100%;

}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.conditions_check').on('click', '.conditions_arrow', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('blue').siblings('.conditions_input').slideToggle(0);
    });
});

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.conditions_check').on('click', '.conditions_arrow', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('blue');
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(0);
  });
});
```

```css
.conditions_check {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2.5vw;
  width: 99%;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  color: #170738;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  margin-top: 1vw;
}

.conditions_check span {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.4vw;
  left: -0.375vw;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.conditions_input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 99%;
}

.conditions_arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: .6vw;
  height: .6vw;
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="conditions_check">
  <span>The user must be subscribed to the chanal</span>
  <div class="conditions_arrow"></div>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="conditions_check">
  <span>The user must have at least X subscribers</span>
  <div class="conditions_arrow"></div>
</div>
<div class="conditions_input">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Всю голову сломал как это реализовать, знал что решение близко, но никак )